# Jquery push elements in an array

Tags: jquery

I am not sure if there is a mistake in my existing code or the functionality in Jquery Array is like below:

```
var categories = [];
$(this).children('categories').each(function() {
    categories.push($(this).find('name').text());
});
```

Now when I have the below XML node :

```
<categories>
    <name>a</name>
    <name>b</name>
    <name>c</name>
</categories>
```

I see that in Firebug the categories array has one element  - "abc" but actually it should be as index 2 with values as 'a','b' and 'c'

Is there something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(this).children('categories').each(function() {
    $(this).find('name').each(function(){
        categories.push($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var categories = [];
$(this).find('categories name').each(function() {
    categories.push($(this).text());
});
```

You are looping through each `categories` element (there is only one) and getting the text of all elements within it named `name`.  Only one call to `text` means only one value.  You need to loop over the `name`s not the `categories` elements.

Comment: Actually, calling `.text()` on a jQuery object containing multiple elements will concatenate the values

Comment: Right, into one single value.  That's why there's only one value in the array.

Comment: No I cannot use `find('categories name')` cause I don't want all of it in the tree node (categories node is repetative down in XML tree). So I have to use `.children` only

Comment: So then use `children('categories').find('name')` don't use two `each` loops like the answer you picked.